# problemas con promise en node

Tags: nodejs, typescript, rxjs

Tengo un problema y es que el metodo que al parecer es una promesa `add.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {` cuando le hago un console el me muestra que me trajo un usuario lo que intento es asignar la variable a otra que esta fuera de esste metodo para poder llamarla en el console de abajo que esta marcado como no se muestra. por alguna razon sale undefined y necesito en ese punto poder mostrar el usuario tambien

```
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private readonly _jwtService:JwtService)
        {}


        async Signin(SigninDto:SigninDto):Promise<{token:string}>{
            const{username,password}=SigninDto;
            
            var ad = new AD(config);
            var sAMAccountName = username;
          ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
            /*  if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
            } */
      
 if (auth) {
            
            var add = new AD(config);
            add.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
            }
            
            if (! user){
                console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
            } 
            else{
              userfinal=user;
            } 
            
            });
           
            }
            else{

  console.log('Authentication failed!');
            }
            });

      //en esta linea muestra undefined
       console.log(userfinal);
          
        const payload:IJwtPayload={
            id:1,
            email:'ajae',
            username:'ajae',
            roles: 'Admin'
        };

        const token = await this._jwtService.sign(payload);
        return {token};

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la función `add.findUser` es asíncrona y al finalizar su ejecución, envía la respuesta a la función callback que le pasaste en el segundo parámetro. Entonces antes de finalizar la ejecución del `add.findUser` se ejecuta el `console.log(userfinal)`, dado que esta imprimiendo el valor por defecto de declaración que es *undefined*. Aunque probablemente existan varias soluciones, yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:
Promisificar la función `add.findUser` y utilizar `await` aprovechando que te encuentras dentro de una función `async`:

```
if (auth) { 
    var add = new AD(config);
    var promise = new Promise((resolver, reject) => {
        add.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolver(user);
            }
        });
    });
    var user;
    try {
        user = await promise();
        if (!user){
            console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
        } 
        else{
          userfinal = user;
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
}
```